# Adding values from datepicker to a list in MVC

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc, jquery-ui-datepicker

I'm working with a booking system in ASP.Net MVC, where I have a `DatePicker` from jQuery UI.
 I want the user to press a button called, lets say `add`, and I want the values from the `DatePicker` to be stored in a list which is then passed on to the controller. I have tried looking for a solution for this but can't find one that fits.

Comment: Since you're working with jQuery, why not make the add button `pus` the date to a JavaScript array. When the user is done adding date, just send the array to the server.

Comment: Can you be more specific on your question? Which values needs to be added to the List? If you want to add the selected date to a list, then you can use `onSelect` event of JQuery datepicker, and then add the selected to a JS Object. Then later use the JS object to make a POST to server using AJAX.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What I would do is just create a javascript array and will be pushing into it the dates you want to add. Then the moment you want you just submit using ajax that array (and whatever more you need) to your controller.

In the snippet I created I tried to replicate that behaviour.

First I created an IFFE because I didn't want to pollute the global scope with my array variable (but you can achieve that by other means, for example using namespaces). Then I just created the add button in the same way I understand you will use it, and for replicating the moment you submit the list to the controller via an ajax call I created in this case a button that logs the array variable to the console (you can see it opening the developer tools in crhome or equivalent for your browser)

Hope it helps

```js
(function () {
    var dates = [];

    $(function () {
        $(".datepicker").datepicker();
    });

    $('#addButton').click(function () {
        dates.push($('#date1').datepicker('getDate'));
    });

    $('#logButton').click(function () {
        console.log(dates);
    });
}());
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.11.1/jquery-ui.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.11.1/themes/black-tie/jquery-ui.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<div>
    <label>Date 1</label>
    <input type="text" id="date1" class="datepicker">
</div>
<button id="addButton">Add date</button>
<button id="logButton">Log</button>
```

Comment: Thanks, do you know how the ajax code would look like for this object?

Answer (score 0):

You can append the values in a hidden field and then pass the values from hidden field to the controller. You need to maintain the list somewhere